# Delete an image with Paperclip

Tags: ruby-on-rails, file-upload, paperclip

I'm using Paperclip to save pictures in my Rails application:

User model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :profile
end
```

Profile model:

```
class Profile < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_attached_file :avatar, :styles => {:medium => "300x300>", :thumb => "100x100>"}
  belongs_to :user
end
```

I try to delete the avatar with:

```
current_user.profile.avatar = nil
current_user.profile.save
```

but it doesn't work. Is it possible?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
profile = current_user.profile
profile.avatar.destroy
profile.save
```

You can't save object this way `current_user.profile.save`

Comment: This way, the file is removed from the file system but the avatar_file_name field isn't set to nil in the profile table. I try to manually set the field to nil with: current_user.profile.avatar_file_name = nil; current_user.profile.save; and it doesn't work

Comment: @MarcoAntelmi where do you put this answer in order to make it work ?