# rails paperclip .destroy & .clear removes the file from s3, but .url is still directing to s3 instead of default_url

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, paperclip

I have this problem where I want to delete the file from s3 and have the system returns me the default url. However upon trying the code below and successfully deleting the files in s3, the url I get still points to s3.

I did the following code

```
user = User.first
user.profile_image.destroy
# i also tried
# user.profile_image.clear

render json: {profile_image: user.profile_image.url}
# the url that paperclip gives me is still points to the s3 server instead of my default picture link
```

Comment: what happens if you check `user.profile_image` after this `user.profile_image.destroy`

Comment: the paperclip attachment is still there and other things like     `profile_image_file_name` and `profile_image_file_size` is still there and not nil

Comment: dont you think that `user.profile_image.destroy` is not working correct.? as it is not deleting profile_image.?

Comment: i just tried something else. upon `user.profile_image.destory` I also have to do `user.update(profile_image_file_name: nil, profile_image_content_type: nil, profile_image_file_size: nil, profile_image_updated_at: nil)` then when I call `user.profile_image.url`, it will give the me appropriate default_url I specified

Comment: You need to save the object after destroy (`user.save`).  See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5343937/delete-an-image-with-paperclip?answertab=active#tab-top).

Comment: ah i see. thanks for helping. can you create the answer so i can mark it as answer for this question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After destroying the image, you need to save the object:

```
user = User.first
user.profile_image.destroy

# saving changes to instance
user.save
```

Credit to [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5343937/delete-an-image-with-paperclip?answertab=active#tab-top).